# Laravel Trying to get property of non-object when sending emails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm making a function that each time I add a comment to a Support ticket it sends an email to the user but I'm getting getting `Trying to get property of non-object` when I submit the comment this only happens if I'm logged out of the users account and only logged into the Admin user

AdminComment Controller Code

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Comment;
use App\Mailers\AppMailer;
use App\Ticket;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminCommentController extends Controller
{
    public function postComment(Request $request, AppMailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'comment'   => 'required',
        ]);

        $comment = Comment::create([
            'ticket_id' => $request->input('ticket_id'),
            'user_id'   => Auth::user()->id,
            'comment'   => $request->input('comment'),
         ]);

       $mailer->sendTicketComments($comment->ticket->user, Auth::user(), $comment->ticket, $comment);

        return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'There was a problem sending your comment to the customer via email');
    }
}
```

here is the Mailer Controller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Mailers;

use App\Status;
use App\Ticket;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer;

class AppMailer
{
    protected $mailer;

    /**
     * email to send to.
     *
     * @var [type]
     */
    protected $to;

    /**
     * Subject of the email.
     *
     * @var [type]
     */
    protected $subject;

    /**
     * view template for email.
     *
     * @var [type]
     */
    protected $view;

    /**
     * data to be sent along with the email.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $data = [];

    public function __construct(Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    /**
     * Send Ticket information to the user.
     *
     * @param User      $user
     * @param Ticket    $ticket
     *
     * @return method deliver()
     */
    public function sendTicketInformation($user, Ticket $ticket)
    {
        $statuses = Status::all();
        $this->to = $user->email;
        $this->subject = "TechWiseDirect Support Ticket - [Reference #: $ticket->ticket_id]";
        $this->view = 'users.emails.ticket_info';
        $this->data = compact('user', 'ticket', 'statuses');

        return $this->deliver();
    }


    /**
     * Send Ticket Comments/Replies to Ticket Owner.
     *
     * @param User    $ticketOwner
     * @param User    $user
     * @param Ticket  $ticket
     * @param Comment $comment
     *
     * @return method deliver()
     */
    public function sendTicketComments($ticketOwner, $user, Ticket $ticket, $comment)
    {
        $this->to = $ticketOwner->email;
        $this->subject = "RE:[Ticket ID: $ticket->ticket_id]";
        $this->view = 'users.emails.ticket_comments';
        $this->data = compact('ticketOwner', 'user', 'ticket', 'comment');

        return $this->deliver();
    }


    /**
     * Do the actual sending of the mail.
     */
    public function deliver()
    {
        $this->mailer->send($this->view, $this->data, function ($message) {
            $message->from('test@test')
                ->to($this->to)->subject($this->subject);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error happens for the `Auth::user()->id` I think. it's because you are logged out of your account. my guess is that you haven't used guard and only have one main user model defined for laravel.